# Synchronization of Progress Dialog in android

Tags: android, progressdialog

I have two activities called Client1.java and Client2.java .

Client1 create a tcp/ip connection with a remote host to run a command.Then server will send the output back to Client1.The output will be displayed in Client2 Activity. As some time is needed to send the output back to the Client1 Activity from Remote server I have used a progreesDialog to show some progress until the output is totally send back to Client1 activity from server .

I need some synchronization that is whenever output will be completely send back to Client1 activity progressDialog will be complete and Client2 will be start to show the Output received from remote server.

Answer (score 1):

[**AsyncTask**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) is the concept to implement Asynchronous threading which is known as [**Painless threading**](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html) in Android because if you implement this then you need not to bother about Threads management.

Now, you just need to write logic inside a particular method.

for example:

1. onPreExecute() - where you display Progress dialog.
2. doInBackground() - Where you need to write long running task, remote call logic goes here.
3. onPostExecute() - Where you need to write coding for starting Client2 activity and also dismiss dialog.

Answer (score 1):

Paresh is right!!! Look an example...

```
private class SessionTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Integer> {

    ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        dialog = new ProgressDialog(TestUI.this);
        dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        dialog.setTitle("UploadFile");
        dialog.setMessage("Uploading file...");
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.setProgress(0);
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
        .........
        } catch(MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e(TestUI.TAG, "E: Malformed URL! " + e.getLocalizedMessage());

            return 1;
        } catch(IOException e) {
            Log.e(TestUI.TAG, "E: I/O error! " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        return 2;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        dialog.setMax(values[1]);
        dialog.setProgress(values[0]);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        dialog.dismiss();
        switch (result) {
        case 0:
            Toast.makeText(TestUI.this, "Uploading finished", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            new DownloadTask().execute(new String[] {TestUI.LINK_DOWN, TestUI.FILE_DOWN});
            break;
        case 1:
            Toast.makeText(TestUI.this, "E: Malformed URL!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        case 2:
            Toast.makeText(TestUI.this, "E: I/O error! Connection was dismissed!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            break;
        }
    }
}
```